# Distinguish between User Checked and Programmatically checked

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have a checked list and when the program loads, I need to load a list of string and boolean to the checklist box. But whilst setting the booleans with

```
   checkedListBoxControl1.SetItemChecked(i, checkedList[i]);;
```

the `checkedListBoxControl1_ItemCheck`-Event Fires. I dont want that because when it fires, it refreshes my database and takes a long time to complete. I only want it to fire if user changes the checked list Check state.

Note: I have

Presently I am using A flag to do that and its ugly and giving me a lot of problems else here

```
     private void checkedListBoxControl1_ItemCheck(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ItemCheckEventArgs e) //fires second on check
    {

        int index = e.Index; 
        bool isChecked = e.State == CheckState.Checked;

        this.mediaCenter.ItemManager.SetDirectoryCheck(index, isChecked);

        if (this.IsUserClick) 
            BuildDatabaseAsync();

        this.IsUserClick = false;
    }

    private bool IsUserClick;
    private void checkedListBoxControl1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Fires first on check
    {
        if (checkedListBoxControl1.SelectedItem == null) return;
        IsUserClick = true;

    }
```

May be my approach of filling the List-box Control is strange in the first place. But due to a lot of unwanted changes along the path. I do it as follows

```
 private void BuildCheckListControl(string[] dirs) 
   {
       IsUserClick = false; 

       this.checkedListBoxControl1.DataSource = dirs;

       for (int i = 0; i < dirs.Length; i++)
               checkedListBoxControl1.SetItemChecked(i, checkedList[i]);
   }
```

`checkedList[]` contains  an array of booleans corresponding to the dirs arrays

Answer (score 0):

You can have a bool variable (class member not local variable) assigned false during your initialization. In the ItemCheck event check the bool variable and decide to proceed the DB check. Once the initialization completed set the bool variable to true.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a boolean, that'll be checked you can (as stated in the comment) remove/add the eventhandler if you change your `BuildCheckListControl`-Method like this:

```
private void BuildCheckListControl(string[] dirs) 
{
   checkedListBoxControl1.ItemCheck -= checkedListBoxControl1_ItemCheck; //Will remove your Eventhandler

   //IsUserClick = false; //You shouldn't need that anymore.

   this.checkedListBoxControl1.DataSource = dirs;

   for (int i = 0; i < dirs.Length; i++)
           checkedListBoxControl1.SetItemChecked(i, checkedList[i]);

   checkedListBoxControl1.ItemCheck += checkedListBoxControl1_ItemCheck; //Will add your Eventhandler again
}
```